# xpath issue of rvest

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, rvest

The code below returns text of `li` after `h2` id containing `best`. The issue is that it returns even when `h2` id does not contain `best`. To debug it, see the output of `li_texts` from `Best ChatGPT prompts for Sales`, it gets repeated. The output should stop till `Best ChatGPT prompts for Games`

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/blog/"
html <- read_html(url)

df <- html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//h2[contains(@id,'best')]") %>%
  lapply(function(h2_node) {
    h2_text <- h2_node %>% html_text()
    li_nodes <- h2_node %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = "following-sibling::ol[1]/li")
    li_texts <- li_nodes %>% html_text()
    list(h2_text = h2_text, li_texts = li_texts)
  }) %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR You need to replace the `ol` with `*`. We want to get the first tag after the `h2` no matter if it is `ol` or `ul` :)

Everything after the "Best ChatGPT prompts for Games (Team collaboration)" uses `ul` not `ol` tag for `li`s, so the next `ol` for all of them are taken from the same place, which is the "Additional resources for ChatGPT prompts" section.

You need to replace the `ol` with `*`. We want to get the first tag after the `h2` no matter if it is `ol` or `ul`.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/blog/"
html <- read_html(url)

df <- html %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//h2[contains(@id,'best')]") %>%
  lapply(function(h2_node) {
    h2_text <- h2_node %>% html_text()
    li_nodes <- h2_node %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = "following-sibling::*[1]/li")
    li_texts <- li_nodes %>% html_text()
    list(h2_text = h2_text, li_texts = li_texts)
  }) %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
```

PS. I wouldn't say I like the DOM of this webpage; they should use some div nesting. The website accepts all kinds of traffic and I treat it as an educational case study.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works. I know "Everything after the "Best ChatGPT prompts for Games (Team collaboration)" uses ul not ol tag". I am confused why it does not respect h2 id containing "best".. I was trying to split the code by using ul ol separately, now I realised that was the mistake I had but I still don't get why it does not respect h2 with 'best' id

Comment: I checked that twice and all returned h2 have the "best-..." prefix.

Comment: In your code,  all returned h2 have the "best-..." prefix. But if I use ol instead of *, it pulls from h2 with id="additional-resources-for-chatgpt-prompts".

Comment: For your code, it takes all proper h2 too. So the engine finds out the h2 with the best prefix and later you ask to get "following-sibling::ol[1]" so now it will look for the closest following ol no matter where it is. You have only impression it is wrong but remember that following-sibling takes next, NOT nested tag whatever it is.